# Nginx rewrite equivalent of AcceptPathInfo option from Apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

I start use nginx. Before I used apache.
And default it worked well in apache (AcceptPathInfo option):

SEO friendly url:
http://testsite.com/anyfile.php/get_param1/get_value1/get_param2/get_value_2 ... etc

As the result, converted from apache file looked:
http://testsite.com/anyfile.php?get_param1=get_value1&get_param2=get_value_2 ... etc

But, how can use it nginx? And it worked for many and for any files: anyfile.php, anyfile1.php, anyfile2.php, etc... a lot of files used it.

Is it possible? Because I saw a lot of answers, but not for any file.

Many thanks.

Comment: YES! Example: http://serverfault.com/questions/429928/how-rewrite-a-uri-in-nginx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not work with any file and any quantity of get parameters. As e.g. my decition. But it's only work with any file, but not any quantity of get parameters: rewrite ^/(.*\.php)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1?$2=$3 How can I add a lot of get parameters? Nginx eqivalent option for Apache: AcceptPathInfo

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index            index.php;
    fastcgi_pass             127.0.0.1:9000 (or your php-fpm socket);
    include                  fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

}
```

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Nginx#Slasharguments